# Who was the old man in Platonia?

Tags: imaginarium-geographica, james-a-owen

In *The Shadow Dragons*, the party that sets off from The Flying Dragon via trump gets stuck in an "endless expanse of whiteness":

> It was an endless expanse of whiteness. There was no distance, no perspective. Just infinite space. Except for the old man.

The old man is dismissive of the group, until he sees Rose:

> The old man didn't reply, but merely regarded them with disdain—until his eyes fell on Rose.
>
> To the companions' great surprise, his mouth dropped open in shock, and his eyes, cold a moment before, suddenly filled with tears.
>
> "Rose," he said, his voice barely a whisper. "How can you be...?

He appears to have a watch similar to Alvin Ranson (and his fellow time travelers):

> [...] he opened the pocket watch, which bore no dragon on the cover, and was fesooned with several more dials and buttons than John's own watch.

He then describes the area they are in as "Platonia", and mentions something called the "Quorum":

> "A new zero point, and here, in Platonia!  This must be brought before the Quorum."

Rose doesn't recognize him, and when questioned about how to leave (to get to the Keep of Time), he abruptly tells them to try the trump again, and walks away.

However, before they leave, he tells Rose:

> "And Rose," he added, "try to think well of me in the future—and in the past."

---

Who is he? All we know is that he's an old man, lives (or at least exists) in a place called Platonia, and is either a member or acquaintance of a group called the Quorum. Who is he, or who does he represent?